# How to exit Arcade game after it's finished?

Tags: starcraft-2

I used to exit Squadron TD games after they finished using menu/exit.  Today I've noticed that every game counts me as a leaver, even though I exit after the HQ is destroyed.

How do I exit without being marked as a leaver?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The game is programmed to count everyone that leaves as a leaver <sup>[citation needed]</sup>, so you cannot do it without being counted as a leaver. There is no official end-of-game like normal games.

Comment: In other words, it's built like an Arcade game... the better you are at the game, the longer you're allowed to play. Of course, in order to play longer, you have to get better, and spend more coins doing so... Ah, the vicious business practices of the 80s and 90s :)